# Is it a good idea to give different sizes of fonts in mobile site?

Tags: usability, gui-design

I am sorry for not being clear. This is about an article page content font size, yesterday I asked my dad to read the article from a website but he couldn't read it properly because of the small font size, then I checked for a zoomIn option but this option is not available in Chrome. I checked some of the other sites but none of them have font change options. It's a common feature I wonder why no one has it Or is there any good reason behind it?

Comment: This could be an interesting question if it had some more detail. @Dilip Kumar, can you probably add a bit more context?

Comment: I agree with above answer... also if you talking about navigation than it should categories Main Nav, Sub Nav (fonts can be different)

Comment: [This Information Architects blog post from 2012](https://ia.net/know-how/responsive-typography-the-basics) still rings true, to me. They advocate sizing type based on the distance a reader is likely to be from the screen, so for "mobile" that would be whatever's readable at 1-2' (about 1/2m) and for tablets, it'd likely be more like 2-2 1/2'(about 3/4m)—more than likely, you'd want a larger size on tablets than on phones.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean different sizes between different devices resolution (width x height), the answer is **YES**!

*Smaller device may require bigger font size*

If you mean different sizes between Title, Subtitle and content the answer is **YES**!

*Titles > Subtitles > content *

If you mean different sizes between Title of same level but different pages, the answer is **NO**

*You can lose your identity and standardization*